# subversion: How to retrieve current list of changelist names?

Tags: svn

After creating several changelists via `svn changelist`, how do I view the names of all the changelists I've created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see your changelists using `svn status`.  If you just want the names, grep for the lines beginning `--- Changelist`, e.g.:

```
svn status | grep "^\-\-\- Changelist"
```